# Logging into ask.fm with Python

Tags: python, http, python-2.7, post, authentication

I was asked by a friend to write a scraping script for ask.fm and thought it would be pretty simple, but I haven't been able to figure out the login process. I've found a bunch of posts about logging in with python, but haven't had much success adapting the code.

According to the Chrome developer console, the POST for a normal browser login only provides authenticity_token, login (the username), password, and commit ("Log in") as form data.

```
import requests  
import cookielib
from urllib2 import build_opener, HTTPCookieProcessor, HTTPHandler, Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#do a GET to the login page and get the authentication token
loginGet = requests.get('http://ask.fm/login/')
data = loginGet.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
inputs = soup.find('input', {'name':"authenticity_token"})
authToken = inputs['value']

#find default values of form fields (<input> elements below #login_form element
cookies = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = build_opener(HTTPCookieProcessor(cookies), HTTPHandler())
req = Request("http://www.ask.fm/login/")
f = opener.open(req)

for cookie in cookies:
    if cookie.name == "_ask.fm_session":
        sessionCookie = cookie.value

#add default values to email and password data
form_data = {'authenticity_token' : authToken,
             'login'              : USERNAME,
             'password'           : PASSWORD,
             'commit'             : 'Log in' }

headers =     {'Accept':"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
       'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
       'Accept-Language' : 'en-US,en;q=0.8,de;q=0.6',
       'Cache-Control'   : 'max-age=0',
       'Connection'      : 'keep-alive',
       'Content-Length'  : '115',
       'Host'            : 'ask.fm',
       'Origin'          : 'http://ask.fm',
       'Referer'         : 'http://ask.fm/login',
       'User-Agent'      : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36' }


#send login using Requests Session
url = 'http://ask.fm/login/'
cookies = {"_ask.fm_session" : sessionCookie}
s = requests.Session()
r = s.post(url, data=form_data, cookies=cookies, headers=headers)

wall = s.get("http://ask.fm/account/wall", headers=headers, timeout=10)
print wall.content
```

When I execute the code, the get at the end always times out. It also seems like the r.content (from the post() line) has the same HTML as the ask.fm homepage, not the page that a successful login redirects to.

Answer (score 2):

Can I know why your content length is always the same? You should also be careful about the form data you're sending, the form data sent to the server isn't a list, it might be something like

```
    authenticity_token=123&username=toto&password=toto&...
```

Try something like this and let me know

Comment: I'm not too sure either...I've removed that line.
This is the Chrome developer tools screen that I see - http://www.screencast.com/t/ioY0tr6wk

The authenticity token that I get at the top of the program seems to receive the right value.

Comment: Indeed, the authenticity token seems to be good, but take a look at the encoding I'm talking about for the data you're sending. Chrome displays it like a list, but click on "View Source" next to Form Data, and you'll see what the server receives. It is not a list, it's a 
        name=value&name2=value2 
string! Let me know your progress.